# How program workitem horizotal tabs in the new workitem web layout of azure devops server 2019?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I'm using TFS 2017 update 1 on premises and now I have to upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2019 on premises.
In TFS 2017 I used a custom xml process model and I programmed "layout tag" to realize workitem web interface with many horizontal tab in this way:

[image: horizontal tabs]

[image: horitontal tabs to manage workitem relations]

I just done the upgrade to Azure DevOps Server and I discovered that fields in the new workitem web interface are automatically vertically rendered, furthermore I didn't find all custom relations but only parent-child and related relations.

[image: new workitem web layout]

I guess it is possibile to program the new web layout form of DevOps Server 2019 in order to obtain the horizontal tabs like TFS 2017. What are xml tags to use in order to obtain horizontal tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, seems you were using [Tab XML element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/layout-xml-element-reference?view=tfs-2015&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops).

It's a Deprecated elements in new work item form  with Azure DevOps.

All the other content of the work item is organized into **Pages**, represented as tabs on the form.

[image]

> The Page element is similar to the deprecated Tab element. However, a
>   Page element can't be grouped or nested. One page defines one tab
>   within the web form.

Take a look at this blog-- [New work item form in TFS 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-work-item-form-in-tfs-2017/)

The nested elements looks like below:

```
<WebLayout> 
      <Page>  
          <Section>  
              <Group> . . . 
                  <Control> . . . </Control>
                  <Control> . . . </Control>
              </Group>
          </Section>
      </Page>
. . .
</WebLayout>
```

A sample page label:

```
   <Page Label="Details" LayoutMode="FirstColumnWide">
                       ......
   </Page>
```

More details about the related xml info please take a look at our official doc here-- [**WebLayout and Control elements**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)

Comment: In TFS 2017 I used a tab to show all relations (both default and custom). Is it possibile in DevOps 2019 to modifiy the default link page in order to better show/organize both custom and default relations?

Comment: @user35631 It's able to create custom link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/link-type-element-reference?view=azure-devops . If what you need is modify default Details--Related Work-- Parent /Child /Related  in the scrennshot to display  horizotal  not vertically rendered.  Afraid it's not able to do this.

Comment: Ok, but is it possibile to add other custom relations in Link page? Otherwise can I add a new custom "link" page in which show custom relations?

Comment: @user35631You can use the [LinksControlOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/link-type-element-reference?view=azure-devops#customize-the-links-control) element to define the options that control what links can be added to a work item and to which work item types. Seems this is what you are lookin for. `Otherwise can I add a new custom "link" page in which show custom relations` sorry not sure about this part, you could give a  try with modify corresponding xml and check if this work.